# Can Powermockito be used with Android Studio 1.2

Tags: android, android-studio, mockito, android-gradle-plugin, powermock

I am using Android Studio 1.2 and the `com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.2.2` plugin.

#### Attempt 1

I include the following in my `app/build.gradle`:

```
androidTestCompile ('com.google.dexmaker:dexmaker-mockito:1.2')
androidTestCompile ('org.powermock:powermock-mockito-release-full:1.6.2')
```

but then the PowerMockito package in not available for import:

```
error: cannot find symbol
    PowerMockito.mockStatic(DatastoreFactory.class);
    ^
```

#### Attempt 2

I include the following in my `app/build.gradle`:

```
androidTestCompile ('org.powermock:powermock-api-mockito:1.6.2') {
    exclude module: 'hamcrest-core'
    exclude module: 'objenesis'
}

androidTestCompile ('org.powermock:powermock-module-junit4:1.6.2') {
    exclude module: 'hamcrest-core'
    exclude module: 'objenesis'
}
```

which is a trial-and-error offshoot of this q/a here: [AndroidStudio/Gradle with powermock](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25136862/androidstudio-gradle-with-powermock)

This compiles but when run Mockito gives a runtime error:

```
java.lang.VerifyError: org/mockito/cglib/core/ReflectUtils
    at org.mockito.cglib.core.KeyFactory$Generator.generateClass(KeyFactory.java:167)
    at org.mockito.cglib.core.DefaultGeneratorStrategy.generate(DefaultGeneratorStrategy.java:25)
    at org.mockito.cglib.core.AbstractClassGenerator.create(AbstractClassGenerator.java:217)
    at org.mockito.cglib.core.KeyFactory$Generator.create(KeyFactory.java:145)
    at org.mockito.cglib.core.KeyFactory.create(KeyFactory.java:117)
    at org.mockito.cglib.core.KeyFactory.create(KeyFactory.java:109)
    at org.mockito.cglib.core.KeyFactory.create(KeyFactory.java:105)
    at org.mockito.cglib.proxy.Enhancer.<clinit>(Enhancer.java:70)
    at org.powermock.api.mockito.repackaged.ClassImposterizer.createProxyClass(ClassImposterizer.java:95)
    at org.powermock.api.mockito.repackaged.ClassImposterizer.imposterise(ClassImposterizer.java:57)
    at org.powermock.api.mockito.repackaged.ClassImposterizer.imposterise(ClassImposterizer.java:49)
    at org.powermock.api.mockito.repackaged.CglibMockMaker.createMock(CglibMockMaker.java:24)
    at org.powermock.api.mockito.internal.mockmaker.PowerMockMaker.createMock(PowerMockMaker.java:45)
    at org.mockito.internal.util.MockUtil.createMock(MockUtil.java:33)
    at org.mockito.internal.MockitoCore.mock(MockitoCore.java:59)
    at org.mockito.Mockito.mock(Mockito.java:1285)
    at org.mockito.Mockito.mock(Mockito.java:1163)
    at com.mdsol.naga.FormPusherTest.setUp(FormPusherTest.java:40)
    at android.test.AndroidTestRunner.runTest(AndroidTestRunner.java:191)
    at android.test.AndroidTestRunner.runTest(AndroidTestRunner.java:176)
    at android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner.onStart(InstrumentationTestRunner.java:554)
    at android.app.Instrumentation$InstrumentationThread.run(Instrumentation.java:1701)
```

Is anyone using Powermock successfully with Android Studio 1.2? Please share your `build.gradle` - thanks!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It should be good already. At least in my case its working fine.

```
dependencies {
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    testCompile 'org.mockito:mockito-core:2.0.5-beta'
    testCompile 'com.android.support:support-v4:22.0.0'
    testCompile ('org.powermock:powermock-api-mockito:1.6.2') {
        exclude module: 'hamcrest-core'
        exclude module: 'objenesis'
    }
    testCompile ('org.powermock:powermock-module-junit4:1.6.2') {
        exclude module: 'hamcrest-core'
        exclude module: 'objenesis'
    }
}
```

Also, remember to select `Unit Tests` in the Test Artifact section of Build Variants in Android Studio.
You need to make sure you are using the right project structure, Gradle version and testCompile.

You can find the article about this here:
http://vexdev.com/2015/05/06/unit-testing-android/

And the whole project:
https://github.com/vexdev/AndroidUnitTest

Comment: For some reason I need to use `androidTestCompile` instead of `testCompile` or I receive: `Error:(135, 0) Gradle DSL method not found: 'testCompile()'`

Comment: I think I see - are you using Robolectric to run on the JVM as per this answer? http://stackoverflow.com/a/29024318/204209

Comment: Nope, I'm not using Robolectric at all. You need to make sure that on Android Studio you are performing Unit Test (Check on build variants on the left, select build artifact: Unit Tests). Check my example project on GitHub.

Comment: @jtomson have you enabled unit testing in the Android Studio experimental settings?

Comment: @SamDozor , This settings is no more experimental as of A.S. 1.2.0, but he needs to switch to Unit Test.

Comment: Ah I see - I was using the old gradle plugin. Switching to        `'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.1.0'` and using these dependencies did the trick! Thanks

Comment: I still cannot use `@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)`.